# update manager, how to update packages

Tags: packages, installing, updating

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution)

In anther post it says, I have to update my packages using the update manager, well, I could not find this. Where can I find it? I am using TexWorks to do my latex document and I have had problems with the `mdframed` package, but I want to update all packages, how can I do this?

Comment: Which distribution did you install? TeX Live or MikTeX?

Comment: You should follow the instructions in [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/5764), based on the distribution you have.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate to me.

Comment: @JosephWright: Indeed. I am out of votes :-(

Comment: I use MikTex with TexWorks

Comment: Follow the directions at http://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/ section 4 "Installing Updates"

Comment: The fact that you use TexWorks does not have any incidence on the problem. You should follow what Werner said.

Comment: Updating MiKTeX is [covered in the linked question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution/55473#55473).